# Type Error when using custom clean_<fieldname> method in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-validation

I am using the inbuilt User model to store user information in my application.
However while registering a new user I want that the username should be unique. For this purpose I decided to override the clean_username method in my modelform. Here is my forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Registration_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password']

    def clean_username(self):
        value=self.cleaned_data['username']
        if User.objects.filter(username=value[0]):
            raise ValidationError(u'The username %s is already taken' %value)
        return value
```

And here is my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect

# Create your views here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from registration.forms import Registration_Form

def register(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=Registration_Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            unm=form.cleaned_data('username')
            pss=form.cleaned_data('password')
            fnm=form.cleaned_data('first_name')
            lnm=form.cleaned_data('last_name')
            eml=form.cleaned_data('email')
            u=User.objects.create_user(username=unm, password=pss, email=eml, first_name=fnm, last_name=lnm)
            u.save()
            return render(request,'success_register.html',{'u':u})
    else:
        form=Registration_Form()
    return render(request,'register_user.html',{'form':form})
```

However on clicking the submit button of the form I am getting this error

Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
'dict' object is not callable
Exception Location: /home/srai/project_x/registration/views.py in register, line 12

The line in question is this

unm=form.cleaned_data('username')

Can anyone please tell me why this error occurs and how do I solve it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the error isn't anything to do with your custom clean method, it is happening in the view.

It is simply that you should use square brackets to access dict items, not parentheses:

```
unm=form.cleaned_data['username']
```